# Rails 5 Mongoid Model undefined method _id has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm writing a recipe rails api with my database being Mongodb. I am having trouble creating POSTING a JSON post that models a recipe for example:

```
{
"recipe":   {
        "name" : "Chicken",
        "serving" : "3",
        "macro" : {
            "protein": "3",
             "carb": "10",
             "fat" : "5"
        },
        "user_id" : "587d5dccb3e9664e280a1199", 
        "ingredients" : [{
            "name" : "Chicken Breast",
            "value" : "3.123"
        }]
    }
}
```

Ingredients is a has_many relation, and i am embedding using accepts_nested_attributes_for. It is wanting the _id of ingredients before it has been created. Its giving me this error when posting:

```
"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `_id' for {\"name\"=>\"Chicken Breast\", \"value\"=>\"3.123\"}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess>"
```

Here are my models for my app:

Recipe Model:

```
class Recipe
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :serving, type: Integer

  embeds_one :macro # Stores object id of macro model in recipe
  has_many :ingredients, inverse_of: :recipe #Stores object id of ingredient model in an array
  # has_one :preperation # Properation steps are stored as an array so one to one relationship is needed
  belongs_to :user # Recipe has one user that posted a recipe

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :macro
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients

  validates :name, :serving, presence: true
end
```

Macro Model:

```
class Macro
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :protein, type: Integer
  field :carb, type: Integer
  field :fat, type: Integer

  embedded_in :recipe

  validates :protein, :carb, :fat, presence: true
end
```

Ingredient Model:

```
class Ingredient
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :value, type: String

  belongs_to :recipe, inverse_of: :ingredients

  validates :name, :value, presence: true
end
```

This is my controller for recipes:

```
class Api::V1::RecipeController < ApiController
  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
    render json: @recipes
  end

  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
    if @recipe.save
      render json: @recipe
    else
      render :json => { :errors => @recipe.errors }, :status => 422
    end
  end

  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    render json: @recipe
  end

  def destroy
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @recipe.destroy
    render :nothing, status: :no_content
  end

  private

  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :serving, :user_id, macro: [:protein, :carb, :fat], ingredients: [:name, :value])
  end

end
```

I cant figure out why its giving me the error when posting. Thanks for some help!

Comment: put a `binding.pry` on the line after `def create` and inspect the return value of `#recipe_params`. It seems like you can't instantiate a `Recipe` with the Hash you are passing in.